# Python3 Tkinter: How to place all image inside a single python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

First, I create an app with Tkinter and plan to send it to my friends to share it but the file contains a lot of images and sounds so I have liked to ***place all image inside a single file.***

**Tradisional method:**

```py
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'something...')
```

**But I have liked to:**

```py
image = ['data of an image like "JHFBJBSBDHSH" or what']
#Then I can use it anytime
tk.Label(win,image=image).pack()
```

I have read a lot of similiar articles which don't help me, I think I shall *read the data in an image* first then *copy&paste it inside my code*. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Here you can read about a solution using `.GIF`: [tkinterbook/photoimage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413849/i-am-attempting-to-code-a-card-game-in-python-and-want-to-place-an-image-but-th/43427296?r=SearchResults&s=1|33.0601#43427296

Comment: The thing is how can I read and convert it?

Comment: @Noobie: It's described in  my link [tkinterbook/photoimage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). [Edit] your Question and explain where you get stuck.

Comment: no your link say that 'convert binary data' but how can I get binary data? I said that "*read the data in an image*"

Comment: @Noobie: *"how can I get binary data?"*: `binary_data = open(<image file>, 'br').read()`. Read [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode)

Comment: It works! I think you may need to post it as an answer to be accepted

Comment: @Noobie: Feel free to write a answer by yourself to show your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stovfl
Really thanks to him!

```py
import base64
print(base64.b64encode(open(input ()+".png","br").read()))
```

Printed out binary data(Use shell)
Copy & Paste the data and then use

```py
IMG=tk.PhotoImage(data=...)
```